# The text of the input in tkinter for pytube

Tags: python, tkinter, pytube

I want to get the text input, which is the URL of the video using pytube, then for the video setting like the title or description..., the output is something weird like this: <property object at 0x000001FB6AA18BD0.

Comment: ok, well that means you are inserting the object instead of a probable attribute of it that is going to return the string of what you need, hard to tell without seeing your code, please provide a [mre]

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example? (MRE)

Comment: Show what you have done so for in terms of code...